# How to get ClientCredentials from a Silverlight app?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight 5 app which connects to a WCF service that is secured using Integrated Security (in IIS).

How can I set the ClientCredentials in the WCF proxy before I call a method or function from the WCF service (proxy) ?